# Issue with Imagick in MAMP

Tags: imagemagick, osx-lion, mamp, imagick

So I followed all the instructions on this page:

http://thoomtech.com/post/8832473042/mamp-imagemagick-lion

Imagick is installed, and I can verify that imagick.so is in the appropriate folder within MAMP.

However, nothing related to Image Magick or Imagick shows up in phpinfo... and when I call `new Imagick()` I get an error: Class 'Imagick' not found

What I could I be missing? I'm running MAMP on Lion.

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to load the `imagick.so` extension in the `php.ini` file used by your local MAMP server.

- From phpinfo, locate the file under "Loaded Configuration File"
- Edit that ini file to include the following.

```ini
extension=imagick.so
; or 
extension=/absolute/path/to/your/imagick.so
```

Verfiy the module was loaded successfully by running the following line in your terminal

```bash
php -m | grep imagick
# Should return 'imagick' on success
```

Comment: See, this is mystifying. `php -m | grep imagick` does return imagick, so I know it's installed... and in the php.ini, I've set the absolute path, which I know is accurate... yet Imagick doesn't show up in phpinfo and isn't being called by MAMP...

Comment: @BenjaminAllison check that your command line is using MAMP's php whith `which php`. If it returns /usr/bin/php try `export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin:$PATH`. I'm running into the same issue btw, did you fix it?

Comment: un-commenting: `extension=imagick.so` has worked like a charm. Thanks